How can for two groups one variable be significantly different but another not if both measure same construct?
Overview:

Two sets of ordinal data collected using two different measures for usability
These two measures are proven to be correlated (also confirmed for this dataset)
Each dataset can be divided into two independent groups (in total about 30 datapoints)
Using statistical significance testing, results of one measure show significant difference while results of other don't

Question:
How can we interpret this, what does this tell us? Does this make sense in view of concepts behind correlation and statistical difference?

This is entirely possible. For example, it is easy to think of measures where males and females are significantly different (e.g. height, weight) and measures where they aren't (left as an exercise for you imagination). Moreover, height and weight tend to be correlated. Having ordinal data doesn't change that.

To clarify, you have 2 correlated measures (say different instruments for the same psychological construct).  Let me know if this is a correct restatment of your query:  ¿How can 1 variable be statistically significantly different for two groups and a 2nd variable not be when the variables are essentially measuring the same thing?

Yesm this restatement seems to be correct. The variables measure the same thing, in this case perceived usability. The two variables are found to correlate

As a general comment, you are measuring a highly subjective attribute (usability). IN such a case, the instrument used to measure this can greatly influence the responses. So it should not be a big surprise if 2 different instruments, both measuring the same subjective attribute, give opposite results. In such a case I would trust none of the 2 instruments. If you want further help, can you provide additional details. What are you measuring the usability off, what are the instruments used, how did you tally the usability scores, what tests did you run, what results did you get, etc...

This question seems clear enough to reopen for me. I think it's one of those questions whose answer just seems "obvious" to people experienced in statistical work, especially if their mathematical background is strong, but the phenomenon may still be surprising to other people. A hint that might make this result somewhat less surprising: if the correlation between instruments is strong but imperfect, would you really expect their test statistics and p-values to be identical? If you apply a certain cut-off for your level of significance, could one be "significant" and the other not?
